# error[E0308]: mismatched types - expected struct `Test`, found `&Test`

Tags: rust

I am trying to create the function implementation add_test to the Test struct, but I am getting the following error.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Test {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}


impl Test {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Self {
        Test {
            a: x,
            b: y,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_test(&self, z: i32) -> Self {
        self.a += z;
        self.b += z;

        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Test::new(3, 2));
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:9
   |
16 |     pub fn add_test(&self, z: i32) -> Self {
   |                                       ---- expected `Test` because of return type
...
20 |         self
   |         ^^^^ expected struct `Test`, found `&Test`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

What should I do to fix it? I tried dereferencing, but the compiler asked about a "copy" impl for the struct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways you can fix the issue depending on your other requirements:

### Move `self` into `add_test` and return the modified `self`:

```
pub fn add_test(self, z: i32) -> Self {
    self.a += z;
    self.b += z;
    self
}
```

### Take `self` by mutable reference and don't return anything:

```
pub fn add_test(&mut self, z: i32) {
    self.a += z;
    self.b += z;
}
```

### Return a new instance of type `Self` with the modified values:

```
pub fn add_test(&self, z: i32) -> Self {
    Test {
        a: self.a + z,
        b: self.b + z,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are returning "self" in "addTest"?

If I understand your code properly, you are trying to add the value "z" to a Test's "a" and "b" values. You do not need to return self.

Comment: The only way I return Self is if I create a copy? I think I can handle this if I remove Self from the return type.